# How can I convert a form field in html to UTF8 using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, utf-8, character-encoding

I have to say I am a total newbie when it comes to HTML and javascript. But I have to fix a small bug in a code not belonging to me.

I have a html form sending some data in iso8859-1. I just need to convert one of the fields of the form to UTF8 before sending it. I have read about the javascript function utf8_encode(). Where should I apply the function in my html code?

Thanks.

Comment: If your html file is in UTF-8 and declared in UTF-8, you have nothing to do to send a form field in UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

Better nowhere :) As [standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html) states, html forms have optional attribute accept-charset. This usually defaults to a mixture of server provided value in response header and information in `<head>`. IMHO the easiest solution would be to set utf-8 as highest ranking charset somewhere. I assume you at least have access to html, therefore you could change the charset for the whole page or just the form.

If you **really** insist on using utf8_encode() please note, that this function is not a default JavaScript function. You should take the text from your input, encode it, and replace original text with encoded. And most probably run into other encoding problems